# Maximum Wait Time for N array of cars in queue to get fueled solution

Tags: java, java-8

There is a queue of N cars waiting at the filling station. 3 fuel dispensers, x, y, z. When a car arrives at front of the queue, driver can choose to go to any dispenser not occupied. If all unoccupied dispensers have less than required by the driver he has to wait. if more than one dispenser has the required liter, the driver chooses the one labeled with the smallest letter.Calculate max amount of waiting time.

Assume taking one liter of fuel takes exactly one second? example A[2,8,4,3,2], x= 7, y=11, z=3, then cars will be waiting 0, 0, 2, 2, 8 seconds.red liter, the driver chooses the one labeled with the smallest letter.

So the max waiting time is 8 from [0,0,2,2,8] in this example.

Reasoning:

```
let 'w' = wait time
A[0] = 2 --> goes to x. w += 0; fuel remaining at x = 7 - 2 = 5
A[1] = 8 --> goes to y. w += 0; fuel remaining at y = 11 - 8 = 3
A[2] = 4 --> can't go to z (only 3 liters of fuel) so wait till 'x' is available; w += 2; fuel remaining at x = 5 - 4 = 1
A[3] = 3 --> can't go to x (not enough fuel) so wait till 'y' is available; so is wait time += 8 now? fuel remaining at y = 3 - 3 = 0
A[4] = 2 --> goes to z. w += 0. fuel remaining at z = 3 - 2 = 1
```

**So, I have programmed with following solution in Java. However, I need suggestion on how to optimize this code with limited space complexity.**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class GasStationSolution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] arr = {2, 8, 4, 3, 2};
        GasStationSolution solution1 = new GasStationSolution();
        System.out.println("Max waiting time " + solution1.solution(arr, 7, 11, 3));
    }
    public int solution(int[] arr, int x, int y, int z) {
        GasStationG gasStation = new GasStationG();
        gasStation.addPumpsWithCap(x,y,z);
        List<Car> resolvedCars = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Car> carStack = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> cars = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

        cars.forEach(p -> carStack.add(new Car(p,0)));
        Pump freePump = null;
        int index = 0;
        while(index < carStack.size() - 1 || gasStation.areCarFueling()) {
            if (carStack.size()>0){
                if (!gasStation.pumpHasCapacity(carStack.get(index).fuelNeed)) {
                    freePump = null;
                }
                freePump = gasStation.getFreePump(carStack.get(index).fuelNeed);

            }

            if (null != freePump) {
                freePump.car = carStack.get(index);
            } else {

                Integer minFuelNeed = gasStation.getMinimumFuelNeed();
                List<Car> filledCars = gasStation.resolveFilledCars(minFuelNeed);
                for (int counter = index; counter< carStack.size(); counter++) {
                    carStack.get(counter).waitTime += minFuelNeed;
                }

                index--;
                resolvedCars.addAll(filledCars);
            }
            index++;
        }

        IntSummaryStatistics max = carStack.stream().map(car ->
                car.waitTime).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).summaryStatistics();

        return max.getMax();

    }
}


class Car {
    Integer fuelNeed;
    Integer waitTime;

    public Car(int fuelNeed, int waitTime) {
        this.fuelNeed = fuelNeed;
        this.waitTime = waitTime;
    }
}


    class Pump {
        Integer fuelCapacity;
        Car car;
        public Pump(int fuelCapacity, Car car) {
            this.fuelCapacity = fuelCapacity;
            car = car;
        }
    }


class GasStationG{
    public List<Pump> pumpList = new ArrayList<>();

    public GasStationG(){

    }

    public void addPumpsWithCap(int ...arr ) {
        Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(p->pumpList.add(new Pump(p,null)));

    }

    public boolean  areCarFueling() {
        for (Pump pump: pumpList) {
            if (pump.car != null) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Boolean pumpHasCapacity(Integer fuelRequired) {
        for(Pump pump: pumpList) {
            if (pump.fuelCapacity >= fuelRequired) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Pump getFreePump(Integer fuelRequired){
        for(Pump pump: pumpList) {
            if (pump.fuelCapacity >= fuelRequired && null == pump.car) {
                return pump;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public List<Car> resolveFilledCars(Integer minFuelNeed) {
        List<Car> carsFueled = new ArrayList<>();

        for(Pump pump: pumpList) {
            if (null != pump.car) {
                pump.car.fuelNeed -= minFuelNeed;
                pump.fuelCapacity -= minFuelNeed;
                if (pump.car.fuelNeed <=0){
                    carsFueled.add(pump.car);
                    pump.car = null;
                }
            }
        }

        return carsFueled;

    }

    public Integer getMinimumFuelNeed() {
        IntSummaryStatistics summaryStatistics = pumpList.stream()
                .filter(pump -> null != pump.car).map(pump -> pump.car.fuelNeed)
                .mapToInt(Integer::intValue).summaryStatistics();
        return summaryStatistics.getMin();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution has a lot of inconsistencies like `fuelReq` vs `fuelNeed`, `Car` vs `CarG`, `Pump` vs `PumpG`, `capacity` vs `fuelCapacity`. It looks like you mixed 2 different solutions or something

Comment: @Ivo Beckers - I have corrected it again. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @SandeepDas What is your question? Also, I have never seen a dispenser with remaining fuel gauge...

Answer (score 1):

A small improvement you can do.

I noticed this code here:

```
List<Integer> cars = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

cars.forEach(p -> carStack.add(new Car(p,0)));
```

It's completely unnecessary to do it in two steps. Just do this instead:

```
for (int p : arr) carStack.add(new Car(p,0));
```